# Strange reRender issue

Tags: visualforce

I am attempting to ReRender an output panel if the end user selects a certain option in the `<apex:selectList>`. When I click save on the `<apex:commandButton>` though the value in `dateWrapper.unit.ReleaseDate__c` gets nulled out. But when I removed the `rendered={!ProjectDatePickShow == true}` it will show properly, does anyone know how to solve this issue? I have tried wrapping it multiple different ways.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection id="loadBy">
    <apex:outputPanel >
        <apex:form >
            <apex:selectList label="View Projects as" value="{!viewAsOption}" size="1" styleClass="slds-lookup__search-input slds-input">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!viewAsSelectionOptions}" />
                <apex:actionSupport action="{!handleDatePicker}" reRender="datePanel" event="onchange" />
            </apex:selectList>
            <apex:outputPanel id="datePanel" >
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!ProjectDatePickerShow == true} ">
                    <apex:inputField id="dateField" label="Release Date" value="{!dateWrapper.unit.ReleaseDate__c}"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!loadProjects}" rerender="projectMain, userFeedback" status="projectStatus" />
        </apex:form>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Controller

```
    static
    {
        if(viewAsSelectionOptions == null)
        {
            viewAsSelectionOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
            viewAsSelectionOptions.add(new SelectOption(ALL, ALL));
            viewAsSelectionOptions.add(new SelectOption(MY_TEAM_PROJECTS, MY_TEAM_PROJECTS));
            viewAsSelectionOptions.add(new SelectOption(MY_PROJECTS, MY_PROJECTS));
            viewAsSelectionOptions.add(new SelectOption(RELEASE_DATE, RELEASE_DATE));
        }
    }        

    public Boolean getProjectDatePickerShow()
    {
        if(ProjectDatePickerShow == null)
        {
            ProjectDatePickerShow = false;
        }

        return ProjectDatePickerShow;
    }

    public void handleDatePicker()
    {
        if(viewAsOption.equalsIgnoreCase(RELEASE_DATE))
        {
            ProjectDatePickerShow = true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            ProjectDatePickerShow = false;
        }
    }

    public void loadProjects()
    {
        System.debug('viewAsOption ' + viewAsOption);
        System.debug('releaseDateSearch ' + dateWrapper.unit.ReleaseDate__c);
        System.debug('datepick ' + dateWrapper.datepick);

        if(!availibleProjectsToLoad.isEmpty())
        {
            availibleProjectsToLoad.clear();
        }

        if(viewAsOption == 'All')
        {
            availibleProjectsToLoad = new List<ProjectWrapper>(getProjects(viewAsOption)); 
        }
        else if(viewAsOption == 'Release Date')
        {
             System.debug('releaseDateSearch ' + dateWrapper.unit.ReleaseDate__c);
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Other than the fact you can replace `ProjectDatePickerShow == true` with simply `ProjectDatePickerShow`, nothing looks amiss to me. Hmm...

Comment: Yea I will end up doing that most likely, i'm going to chalk it up to a bug and come back to it at a later time, it's not exactly blocking me..

Comment: Can you post controller code here

Comment: Where are those components which you are reRendering and using in command button status?

Comment: @SantanuBoral Updated code, the `System.debug('releaseDateSearch ' + dateWrapper.unit.ReleaseDate__c);` is the null value, by removing the render it makes it work correctly

Comment: I dont see any controller code on how your wrapper class code is getting displayed. I think, there is a disconnect between handleDatePicker() and wrapper object's value assignment. Also what happens if you remove rendered={!ProjectDatePickShow == true}? Is that inputfield still getting displayed?

Comment: When i remove the render field it shows, and it passes into the controller .. I also built out a regular property and tried to assign it in my controller and it doesn't work so it isn't my wrapper, it has something to do with my render tag